# (Belarus 1998) functional equation with weird question: $f[f(x)+1/f(x)]=x+a$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

If $a \leq 1$, then there is no function $f : \mathbb{R}^+ → \mathbb{R}^+$ such that
$$f\left [f(x)+\frac 1{f(x)}\right]=x+a$$
I showed that f is injective and for a=0 there is no such function because if we substitute x by f(x)+1/f(x) and taking f from both sides of the equation we get f(f(x+1/x))=x and by substituting x by 1/x we get x=1/x which is a contradiction

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Can you, say, show that $f$ is injective?  Can you find such a function for larger $a$, like $a=2$?  Anything else?

Comment: I note that this is easy if $a<0$ since the image of $\mathbb R^+$ would not be strictly $>0$.  I suppose (but might be wrong) that $a=0$ is the first interesting special case.

Comment: it is easy to show that f is injective and for a=0 i found a contradiction which occurs when substituting x by f(x) +1/f(x) and then taking f from both sides of the equation then substituting x by 1/x

Comment: I suggest editing your post to include those results. Questions posted with no effort shown tend to get closed quickly.  Also, you call the problem Bulgarian which suggests you got it from some IMO list or the like.  Linking to the original source is a good idea.  If nothing else, many competitions have posted solutions online.

Comment: Per [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1653405_1998_belarusian_national_olympiad) the Belarus contest dealt with two cases $a<1$ and $a>1$. The $a=1$ is not considered.

Answer (score 2):

The equality has two implications: $f(x) + 1/f(x)$ is injective, and the range of $f$ contains $(a, \infty)$. Given $a < 1$ (**stronger than in question**), there is a positive number $y$ in $(a, 1)$ that is in the range of $f$. The number $z = 1/y > 1$ is also in the range of $f$ and it satisfies that $y+1/y=z+1/z$. This contradicts the injectivity of $f(x) + 1/f(x)$.

I think we can then argue $a=1$ as a special case, but I have yet to come up with a solution. I'll update if I have an idea, or maybe someone else can come up with something better.